# Aumentar tiempo de caducidad de variable de session en PHP

Tags: php

He intentado varias formas de modificar el tiempo de caducidad de una varable de session, pero ninguna me ha resultado util. También intente modificar en .ini y sigue igual.

Tengo alojado el sistema en cPanel.
Espero puedan ayudarme, Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Te copio una web de un foro donde efectuaron la misma pregunta, 
[Enlace](https://librosweb.es/foro/pregunta/900/cambiar-el-tiempo-de-sesion-en-php/)

[Otro enlace](http://www.forosdelweb.com/f18/cuanto-tiempo-dura-variable-_session-puede-ampliar-431513/) Creo que te puede ser util.

Un ejemplo de como puedes hacerlo es el siguiente:

```
//seteo la vida de la session en 7200 segundos    
ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime","7200");
//seteo el maximo tiempo de vida de la seession
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime","7200");
//inicio la session    
session_start();
```

Para mas info sobre session, no dudes con consulta la [ayuda de php](http://php.net/manual/es/book.session.php)